# Sending an Url to my Api via GET

Tags: php, api, url, get

I want to create my own JSON API with PHP and I want that the user can send Text to my API, especially one or **more** Links. So the Problem is, that this call could look something like this (in a worse case)

```
http://www.my.site/test.php?link[]=http://stackoverflow.com/?as=2&bs=2&link[]=http://stackoverflow.com/?af=2&bf=2
```

The problem is, that I get only a shorter link without the last information (here: bs=2 and bf=2).
This information is threated as GET data. How can I fix this? Must I use any escaping here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
echo 'http://www.my.site/test.php?link[]=' .
      urlencode('http://stackoverflow.com/?as=2&bs=2') . '&link[]=' . 
      urlencode('http://stackoverflow.com/?af=2&bf=2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the urlencode PHP's function.

http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php